# Unable to locate package while installing vulkan and nvidia-graphics-drivers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, nvidia, vulkan

I have been trying to set up UnrealEngine4 for my ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS system. I've followed this tutorial, https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Linux/BeginnerLinuxDeveloper/SettingUpAnUnrealWorkflow/index.html
I have done everything up until launching UE4 with "./UE4Editor". In this step, UE4 opens up but says that there is no Vulkan installed and closes down again. I have tried to install the drivers and vulkan with this tutorial, https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-test-vulkan-on-linux. The problem here is that when I type "$ sudo apt install nvidia-graphics-drivers-396 nvidia-settings vulkan vulkan-utils" in the terminal, it gives the following error.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-418
E: Unable to locate package vulkan

No idea how to fix this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That driver is proprietary. Consult the [manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) how to install it.

`vulkan` package is not something that exists. Probably meant to be `libvulkan1`, but should be installed as dependency.